# Is my Proof of Pythagorean Theorem by Trigonometry correct?

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, triangles, angle

I have a proof of the pythagorean theorem, where I, first trace the angles created by making two right triangles inside a big one. Following from that, the sides $a$ & $b$ are converted into hypotenuse, where the hypotenuse of the main triangle, $c$ is divided into two perpendicular lengths, $a$ $\sin \theta$ and $b$ $\cos \theta$.

Then, I use the basic axioms of sine and cosine for the angle α in the big right triangle, $\sin \theta$= $a/c$ and $\cos \theta$= $b/c$. Thus, the pythagorean theorem is easily extracted from the given axioms.

$$c=a\sin \theta+b\cos \theta$$

$$c=a(a/c)+b(b/c)$$

$$c^2=a^2+b^2$$

Is it a valid trigonometric proof of the pythagorean theorem? It does not presuppose $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2\theta= 1$ in the proof, rather it uses the definitions of sine and cosine, and similarity of triangles ( which comes by the assumptions of trigonometry i.e. through angle- chasing, etc. ).

Comment: This is the standard proof of the result using similar triangles. See, e.g., [this](http://tasks.illustrativemathematics.org/content-standards/tasks/1568).

Comment: But, I used pure trigonometry and did not hesitate to prove the similarity of the inner triangles.

Comment: your argument is circular at its core if you haven't defined the trig functions in some other manner (such as their maclaurin expansions; Re and Im part of $e^{iz}$ ...)

Comment: @Colver How are they necessary?

Comment: Well, what I mean(t) by circular is that it is dependent on the pythagorean theorem.

Comment: If you are looking at $\sin$ and $\cos$ as just being defined as the ratio of appropriate sides in a right-angled triangle, then they are only well-defined functions if you already know that the ratios are consistent, which only happens if the triangles are similar.

Comment: @lulu I too agree with you, do you know a trigonometric proof of Pythagoras theorem without applying Pythagorean Identity and similar triangle properties?

Comment: @JanakaRodrigo  I don't know what trigonometry is without those things.  In my understanding, the basic functions require similarity just to be defined.  You'd need to rework the theory from the start, to eliminate all of that.  Might be possible! I don't know.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the proof is correct and it is not circular! What you do is essentially Einstein's proof, however, expressed using trigonometric definitions of "sine" and "cosine" as dimensionless ratios of two sides inside a right triangle.

In the following text, the symbol $:=$ means "equal by definition".

**Only in flat space**, we have equivalence between the trigonometric definition of "sine" as ratio of sides inside a right triangle

$\sin\alpha:=\frac{a}{c}$

and the analytic definition of the "sine" using Taylor series:

$\sin\alpha:=\alpha-\frac{\alpha^{3}}{3!}+\frac{\alpha^{5}}{5!}-\frac{\alpha^{7}}{7!}+\ldots$

**In curved space**, the two definitions produce **different quantities**, so they are not equivalent.

Why these two definitions are not equivalent?

It is because the geometric expression $\frac{a}{c}$ is **curvature-dependent**, whereas the algebraic expression $\alpha-\frac{\alpha^{3}}{3!}+\frac{\alpha^{5}}{5!}-\frac{\alpha^{7}}{7!}+\ldots$ is **curvature-independent**.

How to verify that these two definitions are not equivalent?

In the trigonometric definition, we have **a function of two arguments** that are dimensional and have units of "meters": the side length $a (m)$ and the hypotenuse $c (m)$:

$\sin\alpha:=\frac{a (m)}{c (m)}$

In contrast, in the analytic expression, we have **a function of single argument** $\alpha (1)$ that is a dimensionless quantity, i.e., pure number

$\sin\alpha:=\alpha (1) -\frac{\alpha(1)^{3}}{3!}+\frac{\alpha(1)^{5}}{5!}-\frac{\alpha(1)^{7}}{7!}+\ldots$

The above implies that only the expression in which "meters" appear is curvature-dependent. Thus, "trigonometric proofs" of the Pythagorean theorem are not "circular" as long as they use the trigonometric definition of "sine" as ratio of sides.

I have given a full explanation in Wikipedia "Trigonometric proof using Einstein's construction":

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Trigonometric_proof_using_Einstein's_construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Trigonometric_proof_using_Einstein%27s_construction)

Comment: Thanks, I also thought about that after finding Einstein's proof similar. Would you mind giving credit to me over there ( Wikipedia ) ? Because, though it is similar with the similar triangle proof, It encompasses trigonometry and in a way, mechanizes upon Sir's proof. There are very less trigonometric proofs out there, and [cut-the-knot.com] lists some of them. Also, I cooked the proof when I was in High school, So It can be said ' A High- Schooler proved The Pythagorean Theorem ! ', Haha.

Comment: Roughly three proofs since 2008. https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/TrigProofs.shtml

Comment: I have prepared some notes on trigonometric proofs in my Wikipedia sandbox page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Danko_Georgiev/sandbox